# Install a water tank without losing main pressure

Tags: plumbing

In my zone, there is a really good water pressure. The problem is that when there is a power outage, the pressure gets really bad to the point that there is no water in the house.

To solve this, my neighbor installed a water tank on top of his house. This made his water pressure to go down to the point that you need to get close to the wall to use the shower (on the second floor).

Is there a way to install a water tank without losing water pressure?

Something came to my mind but I'm not really sure that this would work or if there is going to be complications in the future.

[image: Water tank diagram]

The check valve could be something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B95U5NW) one i found in amazon.

I think that this would yield the same pressure (or close) as without the water tank, but when there is a power outage, it will start using the water from the water tank.

Is this feasible? It seems logic to me, but I don't know much about this so I might be over looking something really basic :).
Will the check valve decrease the pressure?

If not, what are my alternatives for my scenario? I want to have a good pressure and won't mind to have low pressure (but water in the house) when there is a power outage.

Comment: If you live in a hot climate, note that having a tank full of warm water just sitting around can have some health implications.

Comment: I do live in a hot climate (Mexico), what are the implications and is there any way to lessen the implications?

Comment: @Josejulio bacterial (and other) growth is the main issue. Treating the water and regularly cycling the water will help deal with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check valve is in the wrong place.

If you're going to do this, you should use three valves -- one to automatically fill the tank, one to maintain the water pressure in your house, and one to keep your water stash private.

Install a float valve to shut off the tank fill when the tank is full.

Install a check valve to prevent water from flowing from the house plumbing directly into the tank while allowing the tank to empty into the house plumbing (right side of diagram below).

Install another check valve to keep your tank from emptying back into the public water supply during power failures (left side of diagram below).

The combination of these three valves allows the tank to hold water at a much lower pressure than your public water supply, which is necessary to keep the tank from overflowing.

[image: home water tank plumbing]

Comment: Thanks! In my mind the float valve is considered (I though of it as a standard way to install a water tank, but yes, i should specify that in the diagram, sorry for that) but the valve that prevents from fillling the tank from the other side is a a good point. Do you think these check valves will drastically reduce the pressure?

Comment: Also, in this system, will the water tank stall due to having less pressure than the water from the main line?